# Print a column in awk if it matches, if not then still print the line (without that column)

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to do some filtering with awk but I'm currently running into an issue. I can make awk match a regex and print the line with the column but I cannot make it print the line without the column.

`awk -v OFS='\t' '$6 ~ /^07/ {print $3, $4, $5, $6}' file`

Is currently what I have. Can I make awk print the line without the sixth column if it doesn't match the regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `$6` to the empty string if the regex doesn't match. As simple as that. This should do it:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ if ($6 ~ /^07/) { print $3, $4, $5, $6 } else { $6 = ""; print $0; } }' file
```

Note that `$0` is the entire line, including `$2` (which you didn't seem to use). It will print every column except the 6th column.

If you just want to print `$3`, `$4` and `$5` when there isn't a match, use this instead:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ if ($6 ~ /^07/) print $3, $4, $5, $6; else print $3, $4, $5 }' file
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of using if-statements. Thanks :)